# How do I describe a function that retrieves a nested array and returns the values in the specified array?

Tags: javascript

This is what i have for now, but its not returning the values

```
function getRow (board, row){
      let newArray = [];
      for (let i=0; i < board.length; i++;){
        let element1 = board[i]
        console.log (element1);
        newArray.push(element1)
      }
      return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: can you share the nested array and which array schema you are expect?

Comment: let board = [[ 8,9,5,   7,4,2,   1,3,6 ],
                   [ 2,7,1,   9,6,3,   4,8,5 ],
                   [ 4,6,3,   5,8,1,   7,9,2 ],

                   [ 9,3,4,   6,1,7,   2,5,8 ],
                   [ 5,1,7,   2,3,8,   9,6,4 ],
                   [ 6,8,2,   4,5,9,   3,7,1 ],

                   [ 1,5,9,   8,7,4,   6,2,3 ],
                   [ 7,4,6,   3,2,5,   8,1,9 ],
                   [ 3,2,8,   1,9,6,   5,4,7 ]];

Comment: i just want getRow(board, [i]) to return me the row, its for a sudoku checker

Comment: You're not using the `row` parameter in your function. What did you meant to do with it? How are you calling the function, and what did you expect as the result?